# check for a property in array of objects and return a string based on the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects  like this ,

```
   let employee =  [
            {
                NodeType: "intern",
                NodeName: "Node1"
            }, {
                NodeType: "intern",
                NodeName: "Node2"
            }, {
                NodeType: "full-time",
                NodeName: "Node1"
            }, {
                NodeType: "contract",
                NodeName: "Node1"
            }
 ]
```

I need to be able to look through the array and see if all employees are full time then return "full time"  or if the employee list is only "interns" return interns  or if its mixed , return "mixed"

I tried

```
         var interntype = employee.find((obj) => {
                return obj.type == "intern" 
            });
         var fulltimetype = employee.find((obj) => {
                return obj.type == "full-time" 
            });
         var contracttype = employee.find((obj) => {
                return obj.type == "contract" 
            });

    if( internType) {
      return "intern";
    } else if (fulltimeType) {
          return "fullTime"
     } else return "mixed";
```

but is there a way where i dont do this multiple times and instead do it once

Comment: Look into the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert all `NodeType` values into a set, and check the size. If it's more than 1, return mixed, if not return the single item:

```js
const employees = [{"NodeType":"intern","NodeName":"Node1"},{"NodeType":"intern","NodeName":"Node2"},{"NodeType":"full-time","NodeName":"Node1"},{"NodeType":"contract","NodeName":"Node1"}];

const getEmployeesType = (employees) => {
  const types = new Set(employees.map(({ NodeType }) => NodeType));
  return types.size > 1 ? 'mixed' : [...types][0];
};

console.log('mixed: ', getEmployeesType(employees));

console.log('internes: ', getEmployeesType(employees.slice(0, 2)));
```